# displaying text in read only text areas

Tags: html

given the simple code:

```
<textarea>hello</textarea>
```

shouldn't a text area with the word hello be displayed?

why am i not getting that with:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <textarea wrap="physical" readonly="yes" style="height:510px; width:750px">
        hello
        </textarea> 
        </br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Start with changing the readonly attribute's value to "readonly" and see how your browser handles that.

Comment: whether the value is readonly or yes doesn't matter and doesn't seem to effect text entry. At least in firefox 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text areas are expected to be found in forms, not just anywhere. Wrap it in a `<form>` element.

Comment: Works for me without any kind of form (using Firefox 3.6)

Comment: Sure, but you shouldn't expect it to behave that way in all browsers.